# MongoDB search/find by field in referenced object

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have news article and category schemas which are simplified below. I would like to be able e to return all the articles that include a given category name. Obviously I can search by a categories ObjectId _id but I would like to be able to search by category.name.

```
var ArticleSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    body: String,
    categories: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Category'
    }]
});

var CategorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, unique: true },
        desc: String
});
```

Is this possible? Is it a matter of performing a search on the categories collection to return the id and then another on the articles collection to return the articles (this seems inefficient) or do I need to rework my Schema? Thanks in advance.

Comment: rework your schema. you want the category name in the categories array - it's not a good plan to make two queries.

Comment: So I don't need a category schema at all? Or do I reference it by name (if that's possible) I still want to be able to list/add/delete/update categories as well.

Comment: what is in the category collection that you need?  if it had other information about categories or their relationships (to each other) or something else, then keep it - but why have a separate collection just for category name?

Comment: At the moment it just has name and description (a brief explaination of the category for end-users), I did initially intend to make them hierarchical but I am reconsidering particularly if it makes a significant impact on complexity. SO basically all I need to be able to do is add categories (even without any related articles) as well as what i listed above.

Comment: is category name unique? if so you should use it as _id value and then reference to categories by their name which _is_ the id...

Comment: Or if it not unique, and you do not want to store the objectId than store the category name in the categories array, and index the name on the other collection too. If in your application the browsing is based on the category and you list the articles just after it is good idea to keep it separated in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what data has your category collection but for me you have 2 options:

Embed category inside your article
or
Use custom id in category, so your category id should be your category name.